# Creating installer for launch daemon

Tags: ios, macos, shell, daemon, sudo

I have a shell script that copies a plist into /Library/LaunchDaemons with `sudo cp com.example.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons` then launches it with `chown root com.example.plist` and `launchctl load com.example.plist`

This works perfectly when run from the command line but I need to create a way to distribute this shell script to non-technical Mac users, so that they can just download the script, double click it, (probably enter their username/password into a dialog box) and hit OK.  Something like a .pkg or .dmg would be ideal.

I have tried Platypus and appify but neither works with `sudo` because sudo causes it to hang while waiting for input that never comes.  Is there a way to create an installer for this daemon or do I need to make an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could save a script like this as an application in AppleScript Editor:

```
do shell script "echo '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">
<plist version=\"1.0\">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.example</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>touch</string>
    <string>/aa</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>5</integer>
</dict>
</plist>' > /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.plist
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.plist" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! As a note: Applescript applications have to be distributed in a zip folder in order for other users to be able to install them.